# What are the types for the RX JS Observer functions (onNext, onError and onCompleted)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I've got a wrapper function around an RX Subject. Is there a better way to specify these types?

```
let onNext: (element: any) => void;
let onError: (error: any) => void;
let onCompleted: () => void;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can import types right from `rxjs`:

```
import { Observer, NextObserver, CompletionObserver, ErrorObserver } from 'rxjs';
```

Types `XyObserver` only require one handler, while `Observer` all three handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Use these types from RX:

```
import { Observer } from 'rx';

let onNext: Observer['onNext'];
let onError: Observer['onError'];
let onCompleted: Observer['onCompleted'];
```